# Issues sizing overlaying image with Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-audio

I have an audio waveform, page of two images a white layer and a red layer.  The white layer is the resized size, but when the song plays I have been unable to make the red layer the correct size.  I have no idea why.

Here is the bit of code im working with and also a fiddle

```
var imgBg = new Image(),
    imgFg = new Image(),
    count = 2;
imgBg.onload = imgFg.onload = init;
imgBg.src = "http://i.imgur.com/hRHH9VO.png";
imgFg.src = "http://i.imgur.com/WoJggN0.png";

function init() {
  if (--count) return;   // makes sure both images are loaded

   var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
       ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
       audio =  document.querySelector("audio");

  canvas.width = 750;
  canvas.height = 120;

  render();

  audio.volume = 0.5;
  audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", render);

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // calc progress
    var pst = audio.currentTime / audio.duration;

    // draw clipped version of top image
    if (pst > 0) {
      ctx.drawImage(imgFg, 0, 0, (canvas.width * pst)|0, canvas.height,  // source
                           0, 0, (canvas.width * pst)|0, canvas.height); // dst
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tallgirltaadaa/pxezgj99/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the *source* size in `drawImage()` to use the image size as source:

```
ctx.drawImage(imgFg, 0, 0, imgFg.width * pst, imgFg.height,     // src
                     0, 0, canvas.width * pst, canvas.height);  // dst
```

As the image here is larger than the destination canvas you have to use the source size as basis, then scale it all down to destination.

**[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/pxezgj99/2/)**